# Set GridControl column format programmatically (DevExpress)

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a GridControl made by code:

```
GridControl gc= new GridControl();
gc.Name = "Grid1";
gc.AutoGenerateColumns = AutoGenerateColumnsMode.AddNew;
gc.ItemsSource = myDataTable;
```

The problem is that I have a column called "creation_time", and I want to change the default detetime format from dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS.

I'm trying to create a GridColum from the GridControl but I don't know if it's the right way

```
GridColumn colCurrency = gc.Columns["creation_time"];
colCurrency.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom;
colCurrency.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "G";
```

Comment: you can accept your answer if it is the solution for your question.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I thought your answer is better than my and should be classified as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made it:

```
gc.Columns["creation_time"].EditSettings = new TextEditSettings() { DisplayFormat = "{G}" };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you use auto create column and in myDataTable has the variable type DateTime that creates a DateTime column (format without timespan).
One solution is not to use AutoCreateColumn and create them manually, and then you can set the display options (formatString...)
how you write